# Can I install windows in space between two existing linux partitions?

Tags: linux, partition, windows, dual-boot

I have ubuntu installed on my computer. Now I want to install windows near it. For this, I need to free around 20-50 Gb space. But I have the following partitioning:

```
lsblk
├─sda1   8:1    0   750M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     5G  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 144,2G  0 part /home
├─sda4   8:6    0  27,7G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:7    0     2G  0 part
```

So the partition I can resize and get free space from is mounted to  /home. But then windows will be installed between two linux partitions (/home and /). So my question: is this ok?

Comment: **Backup first** and verify your backup is **valid**

Comment: **1** can you show us result of `lsblk`  (edit the question), **2** I wouldn't trust windows installer to handle `/boot`'s grub menu and install itself in a random partition. **3** I would conduct this test in an expandable system (that I don't care to loose).

Comment: So, I have successfully accomplished my task and it worked! 
@Archemar, I made Windows install itself into a new partition which I cut from sda3. And I fixed grub after windows installation. More a less I followed the instructions on this site: https://itsfoss.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes.

Thirty characters are needed for posting an answer. Here they are.

Comment: Thank you for clarification!